# How to get all all key values of an array in laravel?

Tags: json, laravel

I am not getting all the key values of and array using `foreach`, its giving only first key value.

```
$order_id = DB::table('order')->where('delivery_boy_id', $delivery_boy_id)->where('is_accept', 1)->whereRaw('delivery_completed_at < time_of_assignment')->get();
```

When i run this code i get `two key value`

```
 array:2 [0 => {#325
+"id": 37
+"order_id": 8261
+"delivery_boy_id": 8}1 => {#326
+"id": 38
+"order_id": 8261
+"delivery_boy_id": 8]
```

After using this `json` response i am getting the response of only `one key value`

```
foreach($order_id as $value){ $values = $value) }; 
$this->response['items'] = $order_id;
return json_encode($this->response);
```

Comment: precisely! when you `dd` in the foreach loop, it dies on the first try hence getting the first key. try adding a var on top which will hold the array of values then set that inside the foreach loop then return it outside the loop to get all the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Dd means dump and die so it stops execution. If you dd in a for each loop, you will only get the current value in the loop (I.e the first one) because it will halt execution and you will never reach the second loop through. Use var_dump to allow execution to continue and dump variables.

If you simply want to return the Json to the user, you can just return the result of your query as laravel handles serialisation for you. You don't need to loop over the result. See the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization

You are overwriting $values in your loop. So every time it passes through the for each loop, it overwrites $values with the current $value so it will only ever contain 1 object. You don't need to do the serialisation manually, use the laravel helper methods

Also in your code snippet you are looping over $order, but the result of your query is assigned to $order_id? I'm assuming that's due to abbreviating your code

Comment: ya but i am not getting all key values even in json response.

Comment: Have you tried using var dump rather than dd to prevent your loop from stopping

Comment: ya i tried after that am getting both key values. but when i am using this as a json response it give the first key value only.

Comment: Then you need to update your question to include the code where you return the Json response or create a new question because the problem you describe above is due to dd as I say in my answer

Comment: Now this is the code and i am getting the response of only first key value.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
    $order_id = DB::table('order')->where('delivery_boy_id', $delivery_boy_id)->where('is_accept', 1)->whereRaw('delivery_completed_at < time_of_assignment')->get();    

// return $order_id;(returns json array)
    $data = [];
    foreach($order_id as $order)
    {
        var_dump($order);
    //in first loop first array will come
    //second loop second array
    $data[]=[
       'id' => $order['id'],
         '..' => '..'
    ];
    }
    return $data;
    }
```